How to estimate residual variance parameter in the makeLmer function in simr package
I am using the simr package to calculate required sample size for a crossover, entirely within-subject design, where all participants will be exposed to four conditions, placebo and three other formulations of a drug (order counterbalanced) fior pain. Participants will have the outcome of interest measured four times per day for seven days for each of the four conditions. So for each participant there are 4 x 7 x 4 = 112 measurements. We are going to compare each of the three formulations of the drug to placebo. I started with 20 participants
Here is the code to construct the data object
daysPerCondition <- 1:7
measurementsPerDay <- 1:4
participants <- 1:20
nObsPerParticipant <- length(conditions)*length(daysPerCondition)*length(measurementsPerDay)
totalObs <- length(participants)*nObsPerParticipant

# Now we create the dataset
d <- tibble(id = factor(rep(x=participants,
                            each=nObsPerParticipant)),
            condition = rep(x=conditions,
                            each=length(daysPerCondition)*length(measurementsPerDay),
                            length.out = totalObs),
            day = rep(x=daysPerCondition,
                      each=length(measurementsPerDay),
                      length.out=totalObs),
            measurement = rep(x=measurementsPerDay,
                              length.out=totalObs))

head(d)

Now we enter in effects. From literature in this area average pain on a 0-100 scale among people at baseline is 46.4 (21.6). I use this to specify the intercept for the model, and the variance for the intercept (V1 below). From a meta-analysis the minimally clinically significant effect size for a pain treatment is 10 on a 0-100 visual analog scale, so I have entered 10 as the effect size for all three comparisons.
b <- c(46.4, -10, -10, -10) # fixed intercept and slopes
V1 <- 21.6 # Intercept variance
s <- 100 # residual variance

# Build a model object

# Use the makeLmer function to build an artificial lme4 object.

model1 <- makeLmer(formula=y ~ condition + (1|id), 
                   fixef=b, 
                   VarCorr=V1, # change depending on whether random slope or intercept
                   sigma=s, 
                   data=d)

The MAJOR sticking point I have is the estimate of the residual variance (the s argument in the makeLmer() function. The appendix of the article reporting the simr package states. 'Values for these parameters might come from the literature or the user's own knowledge and experience'. But I have never read a paper that reports residual variance. The value of 100 that I used I just made up. Can anyone suggest a good strategy for estimating residual variance in the absence of pilot data?
